# Comments broken in latest MS Edge

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

Using latest MS Edge browser.

Recently, the comments stopped working on all stack exchange web sites.

I press "Add a comment" link, the page scrolls to top and nothing else happens.

If I press "Open with Internet Explorer" in the browser, there it works OK on the same PC.

Update: the console says

```
SCRIPT5022: QuotaExceededError
full.en.js (3,18315)
```

Update 2: The bug is still here. I’m using new PC and much newer version of Edge. Same symptoms, pressing “add a comment” or ”show 11 more comments” scrolls to top, + that exception in console.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Comment posted from Edge on Windows 10 Pro; seems fine to me

Comment: Yes, please see the update.

Comment: This feels like an Edge bug to me. I've never heard of a `QuotaExceededError`.

Comment: @Oded Sure, could be an Edge bug. All browsers have their bugs, however web apps should function nevertheless. That’s one reason why I don’t do web development :-)

Comment: So, you are telling me we should expect and work around bugs before they are known?

Comment: Analogy: your application should work even when the library you just updated has a bug in it.

Comment: @Oded now you know, aren't you? Also, that's not necessary a browser's bug. All browsers limit the amount of per-domain data in LocalStorage to relatively small value like 5-10MB, and throw similar exceptions when exceeded.

Comment: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/04/14/blowing-up-localstorage-or-what-happens-when-you-exceed-quota

Comment: I can't assume that the error that Edge throws means the same as what Chrome does... Edge isn't even mentioned in the article you linked to (and IE - completely different error)...

Comment: I am writing this in Edge, by the way - seems to work fine for me. So, yes, possibly something specific to you - can you try `localStorage.clear()` in the browser console and see if that helps?

Comment: We don't rely on `localStorage` all that much here, which is why I don't expect it to be the issue here. And as I said, given that Edge works fine for me, I can only suspect your setup - did you clear your cache? Disable all add-ons/plugins?

Comment: Thanks, clearing local data helped. Before I was told here to look in the console, I had absolutely no idea why the feature stopped working across all StackExchange sites. I was 100% sure you’ve updated some JavaScript on your side :-)

Comment: Glad it helped. It _might_ be a bug in Edge and localStorage, given we don't really use all that much of it, but... unless we see many more reports of similar, will chalk it up as a one-off.

Comment: @Oded See the update

Comment: Just run `localStorage.clear()` again and all will be good again. Good luck!

Comment: Can't reproduce in Edge.

Comment: @SonicWizard looks like something is making this user's local storage to become full, probably some virus or malware. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard It worked again. However, the site must function without development tools. It doesn’t, and it’s a bug.

Comment: But it's something on your side, otherwise we would have seen thousands of such bug reports. Like I said, you got something wrong, e.g. malware, messing with your local storage. SE can't do anything about it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You’re right, its possible. But local storage is limited per domain: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/storage/web-and-offline-storage  To exhaust the limit, the malware must be in javascripts from SO domain.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It’s not something on my side, this time it’s on another PC which I don’t even use for development. The only two common things, I use Edge as primary browser, and I use SO quite a lot.

Comment: Well... this only proves that Edge is inferior browser with much less storage space than other browsers. Question is whether SE should spend time and efforts on supporting inferior browsers, which I think not. This aside, Oded no longer works for SE, so he can't do anything, even if he wanted to. Now that you edited, the question is bumped, so current developers can see it, so there isn't much more you can do. Bottom line... executing console command once in a while is really not a big deal. Personally I wouldn't mind doing it, if I would want to keep using Edge for browsing SE.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's always worked fine for me and I've never had to execute a console command.

Comment: Only one tabs open on Stack. Had to use the `localStorage.clear()` 4 times in 1h30.