# Compatibility Issues with Edge (QuotaExceededError)

Tags: bug, microsoft-edge

2019-04-16 -- The issue has returned. Please see Updated Additional Info at end.

## ISSUE 1: Broken Comments

If I'm viewing a question using Edge and click "add a comment" the page jumps to the top and I don't get the comment input. One example of where this is happening:

[Startup - is it time to split into two teams?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/26378/startup-is-it-time-to-split-into-two-teams#)

The QuotaExceededError error shows up after I've clicked the link to add a comment. As shown here:

[image: Edge Console screenshot showing errors from adding a comment]

## ISSUE 2: Broken Format Bar / Preview Window

The input window that I'm typing in now (for asking a question) does not show the icons for formatting (Bold, Italic, etc). It appears related to Issues #1.

[image: Screenshot of Ask Question input form showing missing text formatting icons]

[image: Edge Console screenshot showing errors from Ask Question input form]

### Additional Updated Information:

The issue has returned. I've confirmed on the F12 tools that all the network traffic loaded ok. I have all 200's and a 302. No errors. This is after closing the browser and doing a CTRL-F5.

Since the error implies an issue with storage, I checked the Local Storage / Cookies and they seem 'fine' (as seen below). Session Storage (not shown) is empty.

[image: Screenshot of Local Storage]

[image: Screenshot of Cookies]

Here's my browser version:

Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

Comment: Semi dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287297/comments-broken-in-latest-ms-edge. Anyway, the first error is due to local storage issue, you might be low on disk space.

Comment: Can you also check the Network tab. Anything not 200 / 302 / 303 there?

Comment: It's unlikely a drive-space error (I have 30GB free) but maybe something related to Local Storage within the browser.

Comment: The good news is it's now working. This isn't the first time I had the issue -- so when it happens again I'll check the network tab.

Comment: You might want to indicate which version of EdgeHTML you are using.

Comment: Is this Edge in one way or another configured by an Enterprise admin by means of Group Policies?

Comment: I'm on a domain, but we don't really have any restrictions (other than things like expiring passwords). I'm an admin on my local PC.  When it happens again, I'll get some more diagnostic information. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the question with some additional details.

Comment: I still can't repro in my Edge and the line where it fails in full.en.js is a boring key value that gets set in [`diacSubstitutions`](http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js). It doesn't make sense why it would fail there.

Comment: You could try *clearing Cookies and saved website data” from settings (not F12).* as suggested in a comment on this microsoft connect issue:https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15339542/

Comment: It's back to working -- so I'll try a full cookie-clearing the next time.Oh, yes. There will be a next time.